# What is the allowed wavelength range over which the Fabry Perot intensity pattern is formed?

Tags: interference, resonance, interferometry

I'm working with a Fabry Perot cavity with a length of 55 mm and an incident wavelength of 1550 nm. From theory the FSR of the FP cavity can be either computed using the equation

> FSR = λ^2 / (2 n L)

where λ is the incident wavelength and L is the cavity length. Or, we can also compute the FSR if we know the positions of resonant dips and peaks from the resultant intensity pattern.

Considering the reflected intensity from the FP-cavity, and applying conditions for resonant dips, we can write the mth resonant dip as:

> λm = 2 n L/ m

m being the order of interference.

FSR can now be calculated as λm - λ(m+1) which is equivalent to:

> FSR = λm . λ(m+1) / (2 n L)

I expect the FSR from both equations gives more or less the same values. FSR calculated using incident wavelength value is 14.8 pm. But for the resonant dip-related equation I only get the expected FSR over a certain range of 'm'values.

From my understanding I expected the FSR to be same for all m values. I'm now confused about the concept of interference fringes. Is there a range of 'm' values to be considered? Or does the FSR of interference fringes actually change with m values?